# Chromecast stat_hub.cc App isn't supported

Tags: android, chromecast, channel

I installed my chromecast device.
I paid the fee and got registered under Google Cast SDK Developer Console.
I added my chromecast device with the according serial number. I can access http://{my chromecast ip}:9222.
I added a Custom Receiver app (I entered my application name, my application package name, and an https page which simply outputs a headline) and got an Application ID.
I downloaded the application shown under https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-android. It works.
I implemented an application like the CastHelloText-android and set the Application ID correctly. For exchanging messages I use namespace “urn:x-cast:{my application package name}”
I am able to connect to my chromecast device (screen there is turned to black).

But when I send a message I find that mApiClient mHelloWorldChannel are both null.

When I take a look in the LogCat I see the following message:
04-25 12:29:08.422: E/chromium(10689): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:216: [0425/122908:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(216)] StatHub::Init - App {my application package name} isn't supported.

The app contains adds.

Any idea why this does not work?
Might it be an issue with the namespace?

Regards

Comment: In the log that you mentioned, there is references to Chromium; the Android SDK has no such dependency and doesn't do anything with chrome. You need to focus on why mApiClient is null. Compare that with the sample code you mentioned to see what the differences are. If mApiClient is null, you will not be able to do anything, including launching your application. When you say you are successfully connecting to CC, how do you know that exactly? Again, try to fix the issue with mApiClient since that is the key here.

Comment: In app _Cast Hello Text_ I get status code `0` in  method `public void onResult(ApplicationConnectionResult result)` with the _original application ID_ and everything works fine. But if I copy the Eclipse project and replace _original application ID_ by _my application ID_ (generated by the Google Cast SDK Developer Console) I get status code `15`. In the _Developer Console_: I choose _Custom Receiver_, provided an application name, checked _Android_ under Platforms and provided a package name in the field right to _Android_. I also entered the https address of an html page.

Comment: the `onResult` you are mentioning is when you launch application. You should be passing an `mApiClient` to that, so if your `mApiClient` is still `null`, then that is not going to work. Is that part of your issue resolved or not?

Comment: The issue was that my receiver page was wrong. I have replaced it by the one shown [here](https://github.com/pjjanak/chromecast-hello-world) and now I can send messages (i.e. I have a valid api client and a valid channel and sending the message throws no error). The remaining issue is that my screen is still black. I thought that it at least should display _Waiting for Messages..._. Any idea?